GitLab CICD pipeline not sharing artifcacts between stages
I have a very simple GitLab CICD pipeline with build and deploy stages. However, the build artifact is not being retained for deploy, and I cannot figure out how to get the dist directoty to be reatined. YAML is shown below:
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build:
  image: node
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build
    - pwd; ls -latrR dist
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "dist/"
    expire_in: 1 week

deploy:
  dependencies:
    - "build"
  script:
    - pwd; ls -latrR
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq lftp
    - if [ -d 'dist' ] ; then lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no; open -u $FTP_USERNAME,$FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST; mirror -v dist/ $FTP_DESTINATION --reverse --ignore-time --parallel=10 --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .git/"; else echo "No dist directory"; fi;
  environment:
    name: production
  only:
    - main

The build pipeline stage seems to be doing cleanup even though expire_in is set
Uploading artifacts...
dist/: found 45 matching artifact files and directories 
WARNING: Upload request redirected                  location=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/jobs/7052630492/artifacts?artifact_format=zip&artifact_type=archive&expire_in=1+week new-url=https://gitlab.com
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=request redirected
Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 201 Created  id=7052630492 responseStatus=201 Created token=glcbt-65
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded

The recursive listing and pwd command shows that the dist directory is absent from the deploy stage. This can be shown below from the pipeline output:
$ apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq lftp
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package lftp.
(Reading database ... 23248 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../lftp_4.9.2-2+b1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking lftp (4.9.2-2+b1) ...
Setting up lftp (4.9.2-2+b1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
$ if [ -d 'dist' ] ; then lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no; open -u $FTP_USERNAME,$FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST; mirror -v dist/ $FTP_DESTINATION --reverse --ignore-time --parallel=10 --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .git/"; else echo "No dist directory"; fi;
No dist directory
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded

Any assistance would be gratefully received,
Cheers
Andrew

As you already wrote too, from my understanding and on first glance this should work.
Is there any meaningful output at the top of the deploy job regarding the download of the artifacts?

Figured out that the job names need to be separate from the stage names. Working YAML below:
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

prod-build:
  stage: build
  image: node
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    name: 'dist'
    paths:
      - 'dist/'
    expire_in: 1 week
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

prod-test:
  stage: test
  dependencies:
    - 'prod-build'
  script:
    - echo "Tests TBC"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

prod-deploy-tr4e:
  stage: deploy
  image: mwienk/docker-lftp
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  dependencies:
    - 'prod-build'
  before_script:
    - pwd
    - ls -latrR dist # list contents of the dist directory
    - echo "Uploading to " ${FTP_HOST} " under " ${FTP_DESTINATION}; # dump target SFTP host and directory
  script: # Check that the dist directory exists from the build stage
    - |
      if [ -d 'dist' ] ; then 
        cd dist; 
        lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no; open -u $FTP_USERNAME,$FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST; mirror -v ./ $FTP_DESTINATION --reverse --ignore-time --parallel=10 --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .git/"
      else 
        echo "Missing dist directory"
      fi


